# SQL Server Linked Server readonly as security measure

Tags: security, sql-server, dmz, linked-server

I've got a configuration with to separate VLANs. In one of te VLANs, a Microsoft SQL server is running and doing it's thing. I'd like to read (and only read) data from this server from the second VLAN. My solution is to create a DMZ and run a new SQL Server instance with a linked server in it. Is it possible for this linked server to act as a Read Only gateway between the two networks?

So for example:

```
  VLAN 1 (angry outside world)  |     VLAN 2 (DMZ)      |    VLAN 3 (secured zone)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                |  __________________   |    ______________________
                                | | SQL Server with  |  |   |                      |
Office applications <-----SQL---->| linked server    |<-SQL-|      SQL Server      |
and evil people                 | |__________________|  |   |______________________|
                                |                       |
```

Thus allowing the server in the DMZ to act as a gateway.
Is this the way linked servers are intented? And if so, is this intended to be used to provide some layer of security? If not, what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user on your *internal* SQL Server machine that only has *reader* access to your internal database.

The *reverse-proxy* SQL Server connects over the linked server with this read-only login.